# using lodash in ionic2 (ionic2.0.0 rc.0)

Tags: typescript, ionic2, lodash

I was able to install the `lodash` via typings without any typescript errors to my ionic2 (ionic2.0.0 rc.0) project. However I'm getting an error when I try to access any lodash method.

Following is my code in the provider

`import * as lodash from 'lodash';`

and inside one of my methods I use lodash find method

```
let exist = lodash.find(values, function(item){
      item == value;
})
```

however I'm getting this error on the run time (when I access this method)

```
error_handler.js:51 TypeError: lodash$2.find is not a function
```

but lodash has a method called [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.3#find) and its not giving any compiler errors too.

What could be missing here ? TIA

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-import-lodash-in-rc-0/64943

Comment: @AbM, thanks for the link, I was able to get it working by going through the thread :)